# Content staging for different magento installations

Tags: magento2, product, database, cms, magento2.4

We currently have an integration and a production stage for our magento shop. The goal is that we configure and create content (products, cms, ...) on the integration stage and deploy them on the production stage.

For the configuration we can use the magento cli `bin/magento app:config:dump`. But what is the best way to "copy" the content from one to the other stage? The current idea is a sql dump with only specific tables. Is there anywhere a list of tables which should be dumped? Or is there also an other way instead of sql dump?

This is my current sql script but I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=admin --password=*** integration_db \
    catalog_category_entity \
    catalog_category_entity_datetime \
    catalog_category_entity_decimal \
    catalog_category_entity_int \
    catalog_category_entity_text \
    catalog_category_entity_varchar \
    catalog_category_product \
    catalog_category_product_index \
    catalog_category_product_index_store1 \
    catalog_compare_item \
    catalog_compare_list \
    catalog_eav_attribute \
    catalog_product_bundle_option \
    catalog_product_bundle_option_value \
    catalog_product_bundle_price_index \
    catalog_product_bundle_selection \
    catalog_product_bundle_selection_price \
    catalog_product_bundle_stock_index \
    catalog_product_entity \
    catalog_product_entity_datetime \
    catalog_product_entity_decimal \
    catalog_product_entity_gallery \
    catalog_product_entity_int \
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery \
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value \
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity \
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video \
    catalog_product_entity_text \
    catalog_product_entity_tier_price \
    catalog_product_entity_varchar \
    catalog_product_frontend_action \
    catalog_product_index_eav \
    catalog_product_index_eav_decimal \
    catalog_product_index_price \
    catalog_product_index_tier_price \
    catalog_product_index_website \
    catalog_product_link \
    catalog_product_link_attribute \
    catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal \
    catalog_product_link_attribute_int \
    catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar \
    catalog_product_link_type \
    catalog_product_option \
    catalog_product_option_price \
    catalog_product_option_title \
    catalog_product_option_type_price \
    catalog_product_option_type_title \
    catalog_product_option_type_value \
    catalog_product_relation \
    catalog_product_super_attribute \
    catalog_product_super_attribute_label \
    catalog_product_super_link \
    catalog_product_website \
    catalog_url_rewrite_product_category \
    cataloginventory_stock \
    cataloginventory_stock_item \
    cataloginventory_stock_status \
    catalogrule \
    catalogrule_customer_group \
    catalogrule_group_website \
    catalogrule_product \
    catalogrule_product_price \
    catalogrule_website \
    catalogsearch_recommendations \
    checkout_agreement \
    checkout_agreement_store \
    cms_block \
    cms_block_store \
    cms_page \
    cms_page_store \
    design_change \
    design_config_grid_flat \
    downloadable_link \
    downloadable_link_price \
    downloadable_link_purchased \
    downloadable_link_purchased_item \
    downloadable_link_title \
    downloadable_sample \
    downloadable_sample_title \
    eav_attribute \
    eav_attribute_group \
    eav_attribute_label \
    eav_attribute_option \
    eav_attribute_option_swatch \
    eav_attribute_option_value \
    eav_attribute_set \
    eav_entity \
    eav_entity_attribute \
    eav_entity_datetime \
    eav_entity_decimal \
    eav_entity_int \
    eav_entity_store \
    eav_entity_text \
    eav_entity_type \
    eav_entity_varchar \
    eav_form_element \
    eav_form_fieldset \
    eav_form_fieldset_label \
    eav_form_type \
    eav_form_type_entity \
    email_template \
    layout_link \
    layout_update \
    media_content_asset \
    media_gallery_asset \
    media_gallery_asset_keyword \
    media_gallery_keyword \
    mview_state \
    store \
    store_group \
    store_website \
    theme \
    theme_file \
    translation \
    ui_bookmark \
    url_rewrite \
    widget \
    widget_instance \
    widget_instance_page \
    widget_instance_page_layout \
> content_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone your database from the live site to the development site and install Magento as usual with the database copied.